# Adding google support map fragment problematically in android recycle view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, supportmapfragment

i am using google map fragment to display map in android recycler view, i use this code to display google map grammatically

```
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  
SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        supportFragment.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, 
supportMapFragment).commit();
```

but the problem is it displays map in only first element of map container frame layout in recycler view but not all and if i scroll in recycler view then the first element also disappear, for testing purpose i have tried to change background resource of map container and it works on all element but how can i show map fragment in all element

Adapter

```
public class PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter extends BaseDialogMessagesAdapter implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private static int EMPTY_POSITION = -1;

Context context;

GoogleMap map;

FragmentManager supportFragment;

private int lastRequestPosition = EMPTY_POSITION;
private int lastInfoRequestPosition = EMPTY_POSITION;
private FriendOperationListener friendOperationListener;

public PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter(
        BaseActivity baseActivity,
        FriendOperationListener friendOperationListener,
        List<CombinationMessage> objectsList,
        ChatUIHelperListener chatUIHelperListener,
        Dialog dialog,
        Context context,
        FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(baseActivity, objectsList);
    this.friendOperationListener = friendOperationListener;
    this.chatUIHelperListener = chatUIHelperListener;
    this.dialog = dialog;
    this.context = context;
    this.supportFragment = fragmentManager;
}


@Override
public PrivateDialogMessagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case TYPE_REQUEST_MESSAGE:
            return new ViewHolder(this, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_friends_notification_message, viewGroup, false));
        case TYPE_OWN_MESSAGE:
            // MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_message_own);
            //mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            return new ViewHolder(this, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_message_own, viewGroup, false));
        case TYPE_OPPONENT_MESSAGE:
            return new ViewHolder(this, layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_private_message_opponent, viewGroup, false));
        default:
            return null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseClickListenerViewHolder<CombinationMessage> baseClickListenerViewHolder, int position) {
    CombinationMessage combinationMessage = getItem(position);
    boolean ownMessage = !combinationMessage.isIncoming(currentUser.getId());

    ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) baseClickListenerViewHolder;
    boolean friendsRequestMessage = DialogNotification.Type.FRIENDS_REQUEST.equals(
            combinationMessage.getNotificationType());
    boolean friendsInfoRequestMessage = combinationMessage
            .getNotificationType() != null && !friendsRequestMessage;

    if (viewHolder.verticalProgressBar != null) {
        viewHolder.verticalProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(baseActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vertical_progressbar));
    }

    if (friendsRequestMessage) {
        viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(combinationMessage.getBody());
        viewHolder.timeTextMessageTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateSimpleTime(combinationMessage.getCreatedDate()));

        setVisibilityFriendsActions(viewHolder, View.GONE);
    } else if (friendsInfoRequestMessage) {
        viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(combinationMessage.getBody());
        viewHolder.timeTextMessageTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateSimpleTime(combinationMessage.getCreatedDate()));

        setVisibilityFriendsActions(viewHolder, View.GONE);

        lastInfoRequestPosition = position;
    } else if (combinationMessage.getAttachment() != null) {
        resetUI(viewHolder);

        setViewVisibility(viewHolder.progressRelativeLayout, View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.timeAttachMessageTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateSimpleTime(combinationMessage.getCreatedDate()));

        if (ownMessage && combinationMessage.getState() != null) {
            setMessageStatus(viewHolder.attachDeliveryStatusImageView, State.DELIVERED.equals(
                    combinationMessage.getState()), State.READ.equals(combinationMessage.getState()));
        }

        displayAttachImageById(combinationMessage.getAttachment().getAttachmentId(), viewHolder);
    } else if (combinationMessage.getBody().toString().equals("no")) {
        resetUI(viewHolder);
        setViewVisibility(viewHolder.ownLocationMessageContainer, View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.ownLocationMessageContainer.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.main_color));

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =  SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        supportFragment.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, supportMapFragment).commit();

    } else {
        resetUI(viewHolder);

        setViewVisibility(viewHolder.textMessageView, View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(combinationMessage.getBody());
        viewHolder.timeTextMessageTextView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateSimpleTime(combinationMessage.getCreatedDate()));

        if (ownMessage && combinationMessage.getState() != null) {
            setMessageStatus(viewHolder.messageDeliveryStatusImageView, State.DELIVERED.equals(
                    combinationMessage.getState()), State.READ.equals(combinationMessage.getState()));
        } else if (ownMessage && combinationMessage.getState() == null) {
            //viewHolder.messageDeliveryStatusImageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        }
    }


    if (!State.READ.equals(combinationMessage.getState()) && !ownMessage && baseActivity.isNetworkAvailable()) {
        combinationMessage.setState(State.READ);
        QBUpdateStatusMessageCommand.start(baseActivity, ChatUtils.createQBDialogFromLocalDialog(dataManager, dialog), combinationMessage, true);
    }

    // check if last messageCombination is request messageCombination
    boolean lastRequestMessage = (position == getAllItems().size() - 1 && friendsRequestMessage);
    if (lastRequestMessage) {
        findLastFriendsRequest();
    }

    // check if friend was rejected/deleted.
    if (lastRequestPosition != EMPTY_POSITION && lastRequestPosition < lastInfoRequestPosition) {
        lastRequestPosition = EMPTY_POSITION;
    } else if ((lastRequestPosition != EMPTY_POSITION && lastRequestPosition == position)) { // set visible friends actions
        setVisibilityFriendsActions(viewHolder, View.VISIBLE);
        initListeners(viewHolder, position, combinationMessage.getDialogOccupant().getUser().getUserId());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return getItemViewType(getItem(position));
}

public void clearLastRequestMessagePosition() {
    lastRequestPosition = EMPTY_POSITION;
}

public void findLastFriendsRequestMessagesPosition() {
    new FindLastFriendsRequestThread().run();
}

private void setVisibilityFriendsActions(ViewHolder viewHolder, int visibility) {
    setViewVisibility(viewHolder.acceptFriendImageView, visibility);
    setViewVisibility(viewHolder.dividerView, visibility);
    setViewVisibility(viewHolder.rejectFriendImageView, visibility);
}

private void initListeners(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position, final int userId) {
    viewHolder.acceptFriendImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            friendOperationListener.onAcceptUserClicked(position, userId);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.rejectFriendImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            friendOperationListener.onRejectUserClicked(position, userId);
        }
    });
}

private void findLastFriendsRequest() {
    for (int i = 0; i < getAllItems().size(); i++) {
        findLastFriendsRequest(i, getAllItems().get(i));
    }
}

private void findLastFriendsRequest(int position, CombinationMessage combinationMessage) {
    boolean ownMessage;
    boolean friendsRequestMessage;
    boolean isFriend;

    if (combinationMessage.getNotificationType() != null) {
        ownMessage = !combinationMessage.isIncoming(currentUser.getId());
        friendsRequestMessage = DialogNotification.Type.FRIENDS_REQUEST.equals(
                combinationMessage.getNotificationType());

        if (friendsRequestMessage && !ownMessage) {
            isFriend = dataManager.getFriendDataManager().
                    getByUserId(combinationMessage.getDialogOccupant().getUser().getUserId()) != null;
            if (!isFriend) {
                lastRequestPosition = position;
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
}

private class FindLastFriendsRequestThread extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findLastFriendsRequest();
    }
}
}
```

XML layout one

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/view_chat_progress_bars" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_chat_text_message_own" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_chat_attach_message_own" />

    <include layout="@layout/view_location_message_own" />

</LinearLayout>



</FrameLayout>
```

XML layout two

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_width="100dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_location_message_own"
android:background="@color/red">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map_container" />


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am observing only one latitude & longitude values u are applying & that to u r applying item position by getitem. it is showing only your present recycler position will load that will takes more time to load all the list's.

@Override

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

```
return getItemViewType(getItem(position));
```

}

so try this one .

@Override

public int getItemViewType(int position) {

if(objectsList !=null && objectsList.size()>0){

```
return objectsList.size();
```

}

else
 {

```
  return null;

 }
```

}